# Can I configure CiviDiscount for additional participants?

Tags: civievent, cividiscount

The [CiviDiscount Extension page](https://civicrm.org/extensions/cividiscount-extension) lists the feature "Option to apply discounts to additional participants" but I am having trouble finding that option.

I am curious if it can be extended (or used out of the box) for a workflow similar to this:

- First registration of a multiple person registration is full price
- Additional registrations (in the same multi-registration session)
  automatically get a discount applied

Has anyone used CiviDiscount with this feature?

---

*(Originally asked in the [CiviCRM Forum](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,30917.msg132675.html#msg132675))*

Comment: Is there a way to create the same kind of discounts on a non-event?  we're doing a raffle, 1ticket=$100, 2 tickets $180 etc.

Comment: That might be worth a separate question. If you're using Backdrop or Drupal, webform might be the way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that you can use CiviDiscount for the work-flow you are describing.

CiviCRM does have another way of registering multiple participants, and that is with the use of price sets.  You could use this to offer a discount.  However, *this method would only be useful fo you if you don't need to collect any information about the additional registrants*.

If you went down the price set road, you would turn off register multiple participants on the event config, create a price set and and set your event fees to use this price set.

An example price set would look something like this:

- First price field: a required check-box set at $100 dollars (this handles the first registration)
- Second price field: a text/numeric quantity field set at $80 that increments the registration count by 1 (for all subsequent registrations)

**Note:** We are not using CiviDiscount at all in the price set example above.

**Aside:** "Option to apply discounts to additional participants" would probably be better worded as "Discounts can be applied to additional participants" in the documentation.

Comment: So the discount would be applied to the original registration as well as all the additional registrations, is that the default use?

Comment: In this price set example you wouldn't use CiviDiscount at all. I've updated my answer to make this more obvious, hopefully - let me know if it still unclear.

Comment: But then you lose the function of the additional attendees personal information, ie, name badges, contact info, reminders, etc.